# Getting error of "Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [useFilepath] with [class java.lang.String]"

Tags: java, eclipse

Iam using two different classes which generated the latest files in the directory, so this latest file is calling in the main method,but getting and error.

First latest file class file code:

```
 package API_Automation.panaray;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 
public class DataBase_directory {
 
 
    public static  String getLatestFilePath() {
        
        File folder = new File(".//Output_Files//Data_Base");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        File latestDir = null;
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && (latestDir == null || file.lastModified() > latestDir.lastModified())) {
                latestDir = file;
            }
        }

        if (latestDir != null) {
            //System.out.println("Latest directory: " + latestDir.getPath());
            File directory = new File(latestDir.getPath());
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            
            // Sort files by last modified date
            Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
                public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                    return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(f1.lastModified());
                }
            });

            // Iterate through files and get the first file with .xlsx extension
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
                    return file.getPath();
                   // System.out.println(file.getPath());
                 
                }
            }
        
        
        }
        return null;
       
         
    }

}
```

Second latest file class file code:

```
package API_Automation.panaray;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Comparator;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;
 
public class Elastic_Search_directory {
 
 
    public static  String getLatestFilePath() {
        
        File folder = new File(".//Output_Files//Elastic_Search");
        File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

        File latestDir = null;
        for (File file : listOfFiles) {
            if (file.isDirectory() && (latestDir == null || file.lastModified() > latestDir.lastModified())) {
                latestDir = file;
            }
        }

        if (latestDir != null) {
            //System.out.println("Latest directory: " + latestDir.getPath());
            File directory = new File(latestDir.getPath());
            File[] files = directory.listFiles();
            
            // Sort files by last modified date
            Arrays.sort(files, new Comparator<File>() {
                public int compare(File f1, File f2) {
                    return Long.valueOf(f2.lastModified()).compareTo(f1.lastModified());
                }
            });

            // Iterate through files and get the first file with .xlsx extension
            for (File file : files) {
                if (file.isFile() && file.getName().endsWith(".xlsx")) {
                    return file.getPath();
                   // System.out.println(file.getPath());
                 
                }
            }
        
        
        }
        return null;
       
         
    }

}
```

This is the main code which i am calling the filepath

```
    package API_Automation.panaray;

import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.*;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class Excel_Compare {

     
    public void useFilepath(String filepath) throws IOException {

        if (filepath == null) {
            System.out.println("no file");
        } else {
            System.out.println("The filepath is" + filepath);
        }
    }
    @Test
    public   void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DataBase_directory DB_directory = new DataBase_directory();
        String filepath1 = DB_directory.getLatestFilePath();
        System.out.println(filepath1);

        DataBase_directory ES_directory = new DataBase_directory();
        String filepath2 = ES_directory.getLatestFilePath();
        System.out.println(filepath2);

        LocalDateTime date = LocalDateTime.now();

        DateTimeFormatter dateFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy");
        String formattedDate = date.format(dateFormat);

        DateTimeFormatter dateformat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy HH-mm");
        String formatedate = date.format(dateformat);

        Path dir = Paths.get(".//Difference_Excel_Files//Excelfiles-" + formattedDate);
        Files.createDirectories(dir);

        try {
            // Read the contents of both excel files
            FileInputStream file1 = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath1));
            FileInputStream file2 = new FileInputStream(new File(filepath2));
            Workbook workbook1 = WorkbookFactory.create(file1);
            Workbook workbook2 = WorkbookFactory.create(file2);

            // Compare the contents of each cell
            List<String[]> differences = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < workbook1.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {
                Sheet sheet1 = workbook1.getSheetAt(i);
                Sheet sheet2 = workbook2.getSheetAt(i);
                for (int j = 1; j < sheet1.getLastRowNum(); j++) {
                    Row row1 = sheet1.getRow(j);
                    Row row2 = sheet2.getRow(j);
                    for (int k = 1; k < row1.getLastCellNum(); k++) {

                        Cell cell1 = row1.getCell(k);
                        Cell cell2 = row2.getCell(k);
                        Cell cell3 = sheet1.getRow(0).getCell(k);
                        Cell cell4 = sheet1.getRow(j).getCell(0);

                        int type1 = cell1.getCellType();
                        int type2 = cell2.getCellType();

                        if (type1 == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING & type2 == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_STRING) {
                            if (!cell1.getStringCellValue().equals(cell2.getStringCellValue())) {
                                differences.add(new String[] { sheet1.getSheetName(), cell4.getStringCellValue(),
                                        cell1.getStringCellValue(), cell2.getStringCellValue(),
                                        cell3.getStringCellValue() });
                            }
                        } else if (type1 == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC && type2 == XSSFCell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC) {
                            if (cell1.getNumericCellValue() != (cell2.getNumericCellValue())) {
                                differences.add(new String[] { sheet1.getSheetName(), cell4.getStringCellValue(),
                                        cell1.getStringCellValue(), cell2.getStringCellValue(),
                                        cell3.getStringCellValue() });
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            if (differences.contains(differences)) {
                System.out.println("Data is not matching");
            } else {
                System.out.println("Data is matching");
            }

            // Write the differences to a new excel file
            FileOutputStream fileOut = new FileOutputStream(dir + "//Difference" + "-" + formatedate + ".xlsx");
            Workbook differencesWorkbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet differencesSheet = differencesWorkbook.createSheet("Differences");
            if (differences.contains(differences)) {
                for (int i = 0; i < differences.size(); i++) {
                    Row row = differencesSheet.createRow(i);
                    for (int j = 0; j < differences.get(i).length; j++) {
                        Cell cell = row.createCell(j);
                        cell.setCellValue(differences.get(i)[j]);
                    }
                }
                differencesWorkbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
            } else {
                differencesSheet.createRow(0).createCell(0).setCellValue("Data is matching");
                differencesWorkbook.write(fileOut);
                fileOut.close();
            }
        }

        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

The main method is to compare the two latestexcel file and paste the differnec between the excelf file.

Comment: There is a lot of code in your question. Can you please provide an [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: @ÉtienneMiret  am getting and error when i run the main method

Comment: Well, post the error then...

Comment: [Utils] [ERROR] [Error] org.testng.TestNGException: 
Cannot inject @Test annotated Method [useFilepath] with [class java.lang.String].
For more information on native dependency injection please refer to https://testng.org/doc/documentation-main.html#native-dependency-injection

Comment: You do have the import `import org.testng.annotations.Test;` in your classes, but don't seem to use the annotation. What is the purpose of that import? Does removing it change anything?